# Why reading rows is faster than reading columns?

Tags: r, excel, performance, rows, transpose

I am analysing a dataset having 200 rows and 1200 columns, this dataset is stored in a `.CSV` file. In order to process, I read this file using R's `read.csv()` function.

R takes ≈ 600 seconds to read this dataset. Later I got an idea and I transposed the data inside `.CSV` file and tried to read it again using `read.csv()` function. I was amazed to see that it only took ≈ 20 seconds. As you can see, it was ≈ 30 times faster.

I verified it for following iterations:

#### Reading 200 rows and 1200 columns  (Not transposed)

```
> system.time(dat <- read.csv(file = "data.csv", sep = ",", header = F))

   user  system elapsed 
 610.98    6.54  618.42 # 1st iteration
 568.27    5.83  574.47 # 2nd iteration
 521.13    4.73  525.97 # 3rd iteration
 618.31    3.11  621.98 # 4th iteration
 603.85    3.29  607.50 # 5th iteration
```

#### Reading 1200 rows and 200 columns  (Transposed)

```
> system.time(dat <- read.csv(file = "data_transposed.csv",
      sep = ",", header = F))

   user  system elapsed 
  17.23    0.73   17.97 # 1st iteration
  17.11    0.69   17.79 # 2nd iteration
  20.70    0.89   21.61 # 3rd iteration
  18.28    0.82   19.11 # 4th iteration
  18.37    1.61   20.01 # 5th iteration
```

In any data-set we take observations in rows and columns contain variables to-be observed. Transpose changes this structure of data. **Is it a good practice to transpose** the data for processing, even though it makes data look weird?

I am wondering what makes R read datasets fast when I transposed the data. I am sure it is because earlier dimensions were `200 * 1200` which became `1200 * 200` after transpose operation. 
***Why R reads data fast when I transpose the data?***

---

#### Update : Research & experiments

---

I initially asked this question because my RStudio was taking long time to read and compute a highly dimensional dataset (many columns as compare to rows [200 rows, 1200 columns]). I was using built-in R function `read.csv()`. I read the comments below, as per their suggestions later I experimented with `read.csv2()` and `fread()` function they all work well but they perform slowly for my original dataset [200 rows * 1200 columns] and they read transposed data-set faster.

I observed that this is also valid for **MS-Excel** and **Libre office Calc** too. I even tried to open it into **Sublime Text editor** and even for this text editor it was easy(fast) to read transposed data. I am still not able to figure out the reason why all these applications behave so. All these apps get into trouble if your data has many columns as compare to rows.

So to wrap up whole story, I have only 3 question.

1. What kind of issue is it? Is it related to operating systems or is it application level problem?
2. Is it a good practice to transpose the data for processing?
3. Why R and/or other apps reads my data fast when I transpose the data?

My experiments perhaps helped me to rediscover some '*already known*'
 wisdom, but I couldn't find anything relevant on internet. Kindly
 share such good programming/data analysis practices.

Comment: I think this has to do with R needing to guess the class of each column. When you have so many less columns, it does not have to guess that often.

Comment: @Len Is this because I used `csv` format, will it be same if I use some other data formats

Comment: I think this issue will be in other formats as well. However, the benefit of reading in a csv file might be that you can specify in the read.csv() function the classes of each column to prevent R needing to guess them.

Comment: Also, you could use read_csv from readr package or fread() from the datatable package to speed up reading in csv files.

Comment: @Len Yeah that's why `[.CSV]` is most popular data format.
Probably you are right, I will experiment with read_csv() for sure, Thanks. Meanwhile I tried to read these 2 data-sets using sublime text editor, and as I expected results were same. Sublime takes much time to read 'not-transposed' dataset. On the other hand it loads transposed data in relatively less amount of time.

Comment: Especially datatable::fread gives me good results generally. Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes.

Comment: @Len I tried fread() it is blazing fast, but the thing is I am still not able to understand why it shows same results . Transposed data is still faster to load.

system.time(fread('coordinates_and_data.csv'))

> 6.77 seconds

system.time(fread('coordinates_and_data_transpose.csv'))

 > 0.28 seconds

Comment: Still, it has to do with that each column could be of a different class, which means R has to guess each class. That takes time. Since in your transposed dataframe you have way less columns, it does not have to guess that often. While fread is generally faster than read.csv(), it does not solve the problem of your csv-file having so much columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173944/discussion-between-dpak-sharma-and-len).

Comment: In order to investigate the hypothesis about guessing column classes, you could *tell* read.csv/fread what the `colClasses=` are (see their docs). Besides guessing classes, fread is parallelized, but only over rows, not columns (as far as I know), which could also explain its performance diff. You could also read verbose output with `fread(..., verbose=TRUE)` to see the operations it's taking.

Comment: @Đēēpak Shãrmã - Are you using an SSD or Hard Disk? In this context, this is likely pertinent to your question. Can you provide details on OS, disk type?

Comment: @Technophobe01 I used it on a Hard disk. I am using Fujitsu Celsius R17 workstation with windows10 OS. Does it make any significant difference.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is basically about: **is reading long dataset much faster than reading wide dataset?**

What I give here is not going to be the final answer, but a new starting point.

---

For any performance-related issue, it is always better to profile than guess. `system.time` is good, but it only tells you about the total run time than how time is split inside. If you have a quick glance of the source code of `read.table` (`read.csv` is merely a wrapper of `read.table`), it contains three stages:

1. call `scan` to read in 5 rows of your data. I am not entirely sure about the purpose of this part;
2. call `scan` to read in your complete data. Basically this will read your data column by column into a list of character strings, where each column is a "record";
3. type conversion, either implicitly by `type.convert`, or explicitly (if you have specified column classes) by say `as.numeric`, `as.Date`, etc.

The first two stages are done at C-level, while the final stage at R-level with a for loop through all records.

A basic profiling tool is `Rprof` and `summaryRprof`. The following is a very very simple example.

```
## configure size
m <- 10000
n <- 100

## a very very simple example, where all data are numeric
x <- runif(m * n)

## long and wide .csv
write.csv(matrix(x, m, n), file = "long.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
write.csv(matrix(x, n, m), file = "wide.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)

## profiling (sample stage)
Rprof("long.out")
long <- read.csv("long.csv")
Rprof(NULL)

Rprof("wide.out")
wide <- read.csv("wide.csv")
Rprof(NULL)

## profiling (report stage)
summaryRprof("long.out")[c(2, 4)]
summaryRprof("wide.out")[c(2, 4)]
```

The `c(2, 4)` extracts "by.total" time for all R-level functions with enough samples and "total CPU time" (may be lower than wall clock time). The following is what I get on my *intel i5 2557m @1.1GHz (turbo boost disabled), Sandy Bridge 2011*.

```
## "long.csv"
#$by.total
#               total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
#"read.csv"            7.0       100       0.0        0
#"read.table"          7.0       100       0.0        0
#"scan"                6.3        90       6.3       90
#".External2"          0.7        10       0.7       10
#"type.convert"        0.7        10       0.0        0
#
#$sampling.time
#[1] 7

## "wide.csv"
#$by.total
#               total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
#"read.table"        25.86    100.00      0.06     0.23
#"read.csv"          25.86    100.00      0.00     0.00
#"scan"              23.22     89.79     23.22    89.79
#"type.convert"       2.22      8.58      0.38     1.47
#"match.arg"          1.20      4.64      0.46     1.78
#"eval"               0.66      2.55      0.12     0.46
#".External2"         0.64      2.47      0.64     2.47
#"parent.frame"       0.50      1.93      0.50     1.93
#".External"          0.30      1.16      0.30     1.16
#"formals"            0.08      0.31      0.04     0.15
#"make.names"         0.04      0.15      0.04     0.15
#"sys.function"       0.04      0.15      0.02     0.08
#"as.character"       0.02      0.08      0.02     0.08
#"c"                  0.02      0.08      0.02     0.08
#"lapply"             0.02      0.08      0.02     0.08
#"sys.parent"         0.02      0.08      0.02     0.08
#"sapply"             0.02      0.08      0.00     0.00
#
#$sampling.time
#[1] 25.86
```

So reading a long dataset takes 7s CPU time, while reading a wide dataset takes 25.86s CPU time.

It might be confusing at first glance, that more functions are reported for wide case. In fact, both long and wide cases execute the same set of functions, but long case is faster, so many functions take less time than the sampling interval (0.02s) hence can not be measured.

But anyway, the run time is dominated by `scan` and `type.convert` (implicit type conversion). For this example, we see that

- type conversion is not too costly even though it is done at R-level; for both long and wide it accounts for no more than 10% of the time;
- `scan` is basically all `read.csv` is working with, but unfortunately, we are unable to further divide such time to stage-1 and stage-2. Don't take it for granted that because stage-1 only reads in 5 rows so it would be very fast. In debugging mode I actually find that stage-1 can take quite a long time.

So what should we do next?

- It would be great if we could find a way to measure the time spent in stage-1 and stage-2 `scan`;
- You might want to profile general cases, where your dataset have a mixed of data classes.

Comment: I think memory profiling is also necessary. [R data import / export](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html) seems to suggest that different specifications will lead to different memory usage hence difference performance. Since `scan` is functioned at C-level (with `.Internal()` entry point), C-level memory profiling is helpful, but this is probably operating-system dependent. It does not look like that this post can be answered by a single person; rather, it needs solid case studies contributed by many.

Comment: `?read.table` explains what stage-1 `scan` is doing; basically it aims to detect the number of columns.

Comment: Your ideas are important, I got a new way for profiling and I really appreciate what you posted here. I feel I need to figure out what's missing, I will come again with some more experimental results. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wide data sets are typically slower to read into memory than long data sets (i.e. the transposed one). This effects many programs that read data, such as R, Python, Excel, etc. though this description is more pertinent to R:

- R needs to allocate memory to each cell, even if it is `NA`. This means that every column has at least as many cells as the number of rows in the csv file, whereas in a long dataset you can potentially drop the `NA` values and save some space
- R has to guess the data type for each value and make sure it's consistent with the data type of the column, which also introduces overhead

Since your dataset doesn't appear to contain any `NA` values, my hunch is that you're seeing the speed improvement because of the second point. You can test this theory by passing `colClasses = rep('numeric', 20)` to `read.csv` or `fread` for the 20 column data set, or `rep('numeric', 120)` for the 120 column one, which should decrease the overhead of guessing data types.

Comment: Okay, I will try experimenting with `colClasses` parameter. Will surely discuss with you the resutls. Thanks.